# Add index with sort order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, indexing, migration

In Rails, how can I add an index in a migration to a Postgres database with a specific sort order?

Ultimately wanting to pull off this query:

```
CREATE INDEX index_apps_kind_release_date_rating ON apps(kind, itunes_release_date DESC, rating_count DESC);
```

But right now in my migration I have this:

```
add_index :apps, [:kind, 'itunes_release_date desc', 'rating_count desc'], name: 'index_apps_kind_release_date_rating'
```

Which spits out this:

```
CREATE INDEX "index_apps_kind_release_date_rating" ON "apps" ("kind", "itunes_release_date desc", "rating_count desc")
```

Which errors out:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  column "itunes_release_date desc" does not exist
```

Comment: Have you checked the [API here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_index)? It has "creating an index with a sort order"

Answer (score 31):

Rails now supports specifying index order in migrations:

```
def change
  add_index(:accounts, [:branch_id, :party_id, :surname], order: {branch_id: :desc, party_id: :asc})
end
```

From http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_index

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Rails doesn't support ordered indexes.

I suspect that you can safely remove the two `desc`, btw: `kind` is in your where clause based on your previous question, so PG should happily look up the index in reverse order.

Comment: Postgres can look up the index in reverse order, but it is a bit slower.

Comment: Version 4.2.7 of Rails does actually. Look up the syntax for this at https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_index. Search for `:desc`

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to specify `DESC` in the index. It will give a small speed benefit for the queries which use this particular ordering - but in general, an index can be used for any ordering of a column.

Comment: That's not exactly true if the ORDER BY would be like `kind asc, itunes_release_date desc`. It really depends on the query.

Comment: @MarkusWinand: that's correct, but OP's particular query fits the scenario where it doesn't matter: `where kind = ... order by itunes_release_date`.